# What is the name I should use for ActiveRecord in rails generate model --orm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, orm

I have a Rails project mixing ActiveRecord and Neo4j. When I run

> rails generate model Fred

it creates a Neo4j model. I want to generate an ActiveRecord model.

There is a `--orm` flag to `generate model`, but

> rails generate model Fred --orm activerecord
>    ...  error  activerecord [not found]

Same for `ActiveRecord`, `activeRecord`.

What value should I use to use ActiveRecord rather than Neo4j?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass `active_record` as a value to the option `--orm` flag.